# Can't Receive bytes with c# sockets

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm trying trying to make a simple chatting server. The server accepts the connection from the client but isn't receiving any bytes, I'm very new to C# in general and OOP so this might be something totally unrelated to sockets and just in my code, I've tried looking at examples of socket connections with c# but I can't implement it to my program due to my lack of knowledge.

```
//server

using System;
using System.Net; 
using System.Net.Sockets; 
using System.Text;



namespace SocketLogger
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            startServer();
            
        }
        public static void startServer()
        {
            IPAddress IPaddr = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").AddressList[0];
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPaddr, 6969);
            TcpClient client = default(TcpClient);
            
            try
            {
                listener.Start();
                Console.WriteLine("Server Has Started");

            }
            catch(Exception err)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("error:" + err);
            }
            while(true)
            {
                listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                Console.WriteLine("Accepted Client");
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
                stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                Console.WriteLine(message);
                Console.Read();

            }
        }
 
    }
}
```

```
//client
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace ClientConnect
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            startClientConnection();
        }
        public static void startClientConnection()
        {
            string testString = "hello";
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 6969);
   //the teststring is for testing purposes
            int SentBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(testString);
            byte[] sendBuffer = new byte[SentBytes];
            sendBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(testString);   
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            stream.Write(sendBuffer, 0, sendBuffer.Length);
            stream.Close();
            client.Close();
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the port you are using is free ?

Comment: @StefanoCavion yep nothing is running on port 6969, also if that was the case the client wouldn't connect but in my case the client does connect but the test message isn't being sent and I'm not sure why

Comment: Do not use Localost nor loopback 127.0.0.1 they may not work depending on how the PC is configured.  For server always listen using IPAddress.Any.  The client should connect to the PC IP Address or computer name.  Most PCs these day use for address zero IPV6 (not IPV4) so to get an IPV4 use addrress 1 : IPAddress IPaddr = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").AddressList[0];

Comment: Don't ignore return values - as well as missing the actual client as pointed out in aamartin2k's answer, you're not paying attention to the return value from `Read` - which tells you *how many bytes you actually got*. You need to pay attention to that, especially because there's no guarantee it'll match up with how many bytes the other side provided to any particular `Write` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to test your code on my machine I had to change the way you provide IPAddress to the server. This:

```
IPAddress IPaddr = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").AddressList[0];
```

sets IPaddr with an IPv6 address. And this, on client code:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 6969);
```

gives client an IPv4 address. So I changed the server code to:

```
// IPAddress IPaddr = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").AddressList[0];
    IPAddress IPaddr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
```

Moving on to the next issue, the server is missing the client bytes because is doing two AcceptTcpClient(). Change the code to:

```
//listener.AcceptTcpClient();
   byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
   client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
   Console.WriteLine("Accepted Client");
```

And it will receive the string.