# Tcp connection fails on LAN

Tags: c#, tcp, network-programming, lan

I am trying to send a message from my laptop to my desktop over the LAN.

I have written a Tcp server that listens for a connection on a port, and a client that tries to connect to it and send a simple string as a message.

Server:

```
void Listen()
{
    listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);

    listener.Start();

    while (true)
    {
        Debug.Log($"listening to {listener.LocalEndpoint}...");

        var socket = listener.AcceptSocket();
        Debug.Log("connected!");

        var bytes = new byte[100];
        int k = socket.Receive(bytes);
        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, k);

        Debug.Log(data);
        socket.Send(new byte[] {1});

        Debug.Log("responded");

        socket.Close();
        Debug.Log("closed connection");
    }
}
```

Client:

```
public void Send()
{
    client = new TcpClient();
    Debug.Log("connecting...");

    client.Connect("192.168.0.12", port);
    
    Debug.Log("connected!");
    
    var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello!");

    var stream = client.GetStream();

    Debug.Log("sending data");
    
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

    Debug.Log("data sent! waiting for response...");

    var reply = new byte[100];
    stream.Read(reply,0,100);
    
    Debug.Log("received response");
    
    client.Close();
}
```

They communicate correctly when they are both on the same machine, but the client never connects to the server when I am running it on a different machine.

I have a rule in my firewall that allows an incoming connection through the port I have specified.

I have tried it with both computer's firewalls off and the connection still doesn't go through.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong there. I'd break out Wireshark -- make sure that the client is sending the correct packets to initiate the connection, and see whether they arrive on the server. Also use `ping` for a quick sanity-check

Comment: You do not have a route between the machines.  You may need to use the computer name instead of the IP address on the client.  You can verify if you have a route from cmd.exe >Ping IP (or computer name).  It is possible you may have to machines with same IP address which can cause problems.  A quick test would be to disconnect the ethernet cable from server and then ping and see if you get a response.  It is also possible ping with work in one direction and not the other.  So try ping on server and use the client IP (or name).

Comment: @jdweng When my laptop (client) pings my desktop's (server) ethernet ip (192.168.0.2), it gets a response. When I am on my desktop and I ping my laptop's wireless ip (192.168.0.13), the request times out. When I launch my project and try to connect to the ethernet ip, the connection times out and the server never acknowledges it. How would I go about setting up a route between the machines?

Comment: You do not have a route to the machine.  Ping must work before you run the c# application.  The masks are probably wrong.  You need to run from cmd.exe on desktop >IPConfig/all.  You can also try ping with the machine name.  The masks have to create a unique range of addresses.  I think the ethernet mask and wireless mask are overlapping so the ethernet IP is going out the wireless (or the opposite).  The laptop is probably a private IP and the ethernet a public IP.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63504490/cant-receive-bytes-with-c-sharp-sockets/63505842#63505842)